# Load and save single objects to workspaces in R/R-Studio

Tags: r

I like the idea of working with workspaces. 
So far I always saved entire workspaces and loaded them entirely to an existing project. But a lot of times I only need single objects from a specified workspace. Is there a possibility to load them seperatly from another workspace.

Also sometimes it would be nice to add an object to an already existing workspace. Imagine for example you have five huge scripts with seperatly huge workspaces and you don't want to mix them up to have them all in one workspace. So now you want to store only the clean results from each of the five worspaces to another clean workspace...

So theses are the basic tasks:

```
# save entire workspace
save.image("mypath/myworkspace")

# load entire workspace
load ("mypath/myworkspace")

# save a single object (or several)
save (myobject,file="mypath/myworkspace")

# load a single object from an existing workspace
?

# add a single object to an existing workspace
?
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question (can't think of a solution to this), but you might consider organizing your data into lists rather than workspaces. Then use attach(list) and detach(list) as you need objects from differing projects/subprojects. Naturally, you can always access individual objects from any list at any time.

Comment: `?saveRDS` comes to mind.

Comment: @ Roland. I tried your hint and I think its problematic with R-Studio. I got an error message that is also discussed here: http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/318-error-bad-restore-file-magic-number

Answer (score 17, accepted):

RStudio calls your `globalenv()` your "workspace"

You can load .RData files into environments other than your `globalenv()`

```
x <- 1; y <- 2 #First, create some objects
save.image()  # save workspace to disk
rm(list=ls()) # remove everything from workspace
tmp.env <- new.env() # create a temporary environment
load(".RData", envir=tmp.env) # load workspace into temporary environment
x <- get("x", pos=tmp.env) # get the objects you need into your globalenv()
#x <- tmp.env$x # equivalent to previous line
rm(tmp.env) # remove the temporary environment to free up memory
```

Once an object is in your `globalenv()`, it will show up in RStudio's "Workspace" tab.

Similarly, you can assign objects into the environment.

```
tmp.env <- new.env()
load(".RData", envir=tmp.env) # load workspace into temporary environment
assign("z", 10, pos=tmp.env)
#tmp.env$z <- 10 # equivalent to previous line
```

Now, you can save all the objects in `tmp.env` if you tell `save` where they are located.

```
save(list=ls(all.names=TRUE, pos=tmp.env), envir=tmp.env, file="test.RData")
rm(tmp.env)
```

You have effectively added an object, `z`, to the workspace stored in test.RData.

```
rm(list=ls(all.names=TRUE))
load("test.RData")

> ls()
[1] "x"       "y"       "z"
```

Answer (score 3):

`# load a single object from an existing workspace`

You can't restore one object from the workspace. Since `save.image(".Rdata")` is just a simplified command for `save(list = ls(all=TRUE), file= ".RData")`. When you use `load` command you restore all objects from that list.

However you can save couple objects merged in a list and then load them. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl)))
d<-c + geom_bar(width=.5)  # create two graphs 
c<- c + geom_bar()
save(list=c("c","d"),file="myobjects") # save them (notice that objects are accessed as strings)
rm(list = ls()) # remove from the memory
load(file="myobjects") # load again
```

You now have your objects (plots) c and d back. That answers your last question.

Now, suppose you already have objects `c` and `d` in file `myobjects` and you want to add more objects to this file. Without loading it it's impossible, since `save` and `saveRDS` stores data compressed (in case of `save` you get tar package and in `saveRDS` you get to choose compressing method). As you know you cant add data to already archived files without unpacking it. The only solution I see is this. Suppose we want to add `a` and `b` to `myobjects`.

```
library(ggplot2)
a<-qplot(rnorm(100))
b<-qplot(rnorm(200))
list=ls()
list<-list[-which(list%in%c("a","b"))] # list all variables except the one you want to save
rm(list=list) # we're deleting all except a and b
load(file="myobjects") # loading or unpacking objects c and d
save(list=ls(),file="myobjects") # saving objects a,b,c,d in myobjects file
```

This is a rough workaround, however if you think about it, in R we got either data or plot objects (i used ggplot2 examples for reason). Data can be saved as `save.table`, plots can be stored to list of grobs (package `gridExtra`) and then saved with `save`.

Comment: This seems to be what the poster already knows how to do (see the third save example in the posted code).

Comment: Considering there was no code with the load example and demonstration of object loading I suppose your argument is at least highly doubtful. New object addition from file this is exactly what code does, read carefully.

Comment: Actually ndoogan is right. I mean I can also save several objects as posted under line three like this: `save (myobject1,myobject2,etc.,file="mypath/myworkspace")`. theres isn't actually a need for making a list before saving the objects together. The question above is more about adding a single object to an already existing workspace (without loosing the other objects from it by overwriting it) or retriving a single object from an existing workspace without loading it entirely...

Comment: also, `rm(list)` will remove the object named `list`.  You meant to write `rm(list=list)`

Comment: @GSee thx for edit. Your solution is equally good, however once you have big datasets, holding couple environments could be very problematic in terms of memory shortage.